# Lucene query syntax support time

Tags: lucene

Can Lucene query syntax support time only search?

For example, I would like to check those records that are accessed before 7:30am and after 7:00pm. How can I write in Lucene?

Comment: Take a look at the notes and guidelines in the [DateTools](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_7_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/DateTools.html) class. That may give you some ideas to get started.

Comment: Other questions: What query parser are you using, and what have you tried already?  What does your source data look like? Can you clarify what you mean by "_accessed after before 7:30am_"? Is it "after" or "before"? Can you [edit] your question to show these details?